# Javascript Uncaught ReferenceError: grp is not defined

Tags: django, django-admin

This error occured in the admin model object list panels. This caused the select all checkbox to not work.

```
(grp.jQuery);
```

Is at the end of a few admin js files. Yet I cannot find where grp is defined.

Reinstalling django did not work for me.

Edit: This problem occured after I uninstalled grappelli, I am fairly sure I have removed everything related to that.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it is because of grappelli, just try removing cache/collectstatic if you ever uninstall grappelli